# How I play my audios with match all text in text box

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, audio, media-player, multimedia

```
        string line = textBox1.Text.ToString();

        string[] words = line.Split();

        foreach (string word in words)
        {

            if (word.Contains("ඉ"))
            {
                SoundPlayer sndplayr = new SoundPlayer(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources._a);
                sndplayr.Play();
            }

            if (word.Contains("අ"))
            {
                SoundPlayer sndplayr = new SoundPlayer(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.la);
                sndplayr.Play();
            }

            }

        }
        }
```

i used this but it play only text box last character audio.i want to play the other characters also. so what can i do. please help me............

Answer (score 1):

use `break` after each `if (word.Contains){...}`.

And use [SoundPlayer.PlaySync Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync.aspx) instead of `SoundPlayer.Play`. by this you can start next sound after previous sound ended.

Comment: thanx a lot, i used break now it's play only very first character please help play the other characters.

Comment: I updated my answer. use `SoundPlayer.PlaySync`.

Comment: yes.OHHHH, I have another problem it will play all character. but it play not the right order it play only i defined order. how can i solved this.please help me...........